# dynamic user form field populating with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a model:

```
class ok(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    depends_on = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have model form.

```
class okForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = ok
       fields='__all__'
```

I am getting first 3 fields: name, project, story from a backend api call. Now I want to populate the last two fields with respect to 
first three fields using AJAX call or jQuery or Javascript anything like that.

I want to auto populate the last two fields from MySQL database in the front end itself before user submits the form.

Comment: Do you have access to make the backend return the last 2 fields when you make the backend API call'?

Comment: yes , after getting the first three fields from back end call , i want to run a mysql query in the front end itself to filter out last two fields , and want to auto populate if existing data is there in mysql before user submit the form and data store in mysql server

Comment: I'm afraid you don't want to run a MySQL query in the frontend itself. Kindly update your question with the result of the backend api call and a snippet of the form markup that is rendered in the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to make an AJAX call to your Django app, which will pass the three existing values as request paramenters, you want to write an API view in Django that returns the last two values:

```
class okAPI(View):
    def get(self, request):
        name = request.GET.get('name')
        project = request.GET.get('project')
        story = request.GET.get('story')
        if name and project and story:
            try:
                obj = ok.objects.get(name=name, project=project, story=story)
                return JsonResponse(data={
                    'depends_on': ok_obj.depends_on,
                    'rfc': ok_obj.rfc}, status=200)
            except ok.DoesNotExist:
                 pass
        return JsonResponse(data={'error': 'bad request'}, status=400)
```

Now in your `.done()` jQuery handler, check the status value and if it's 200, you can access `data.depends_on` and `data.rfc`.

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: and how i will make a call with the last three fields , as user stil has not filled the form .

Comment: what last three fields? you're talking about the **first** 3 fields, which you already have in your front-end (`name`, `project` and `story` you receive from the external API call); the last **2** fields you said you wanted to fetch from the back-end based on the first 3 fields.